# VSCode not showing compiled JS file after running tsc

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm just starting to play with Typescript, using a course on Udemy.

I created a simple index.ts file, compiled it in a terminal, but the generated index.js file is not showing up in the VSCode Explorer. (Even though I've hit the refresh button, and even restarted VSCode.)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: can you share the screen shot?

Comment: Have you configured `files.exclude` in your VS Code user settings?

Comment: Bingo @MattBierner. Thank you. Did you want to put in the form of an answer, and I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking your `files.exclude` setting in VS Code. This setting allows you to hide files in the VS Code explorer using glob patterns. Look for a pattern such as `"*.js": true`. Many TypeScript tutorials for VS Code will recommend configuring this setting so that your compiled JS file don't clutter up the VS Code explorer or show up in quick open / search results

You can configure `files.exclude` both as a user setting or as a workspace setting, so be sure to check in both locations. See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) for more info about managing settings.